# Azure AD B2C Token Expiry MSAL in Native Android

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I was integrating azure adb2c on my native android app using `MSAL`. My token expiry is set to 60minutes in the portal. Currently I'm calling the `acquireTokenSilentAsync` each time the app launches in order to make sure `access token is not expired`. But is there any way to avoid calling `acquireTokenSilentAsync` each time and make the call happens only when the `access token` expires? This is to make the app load much faster,by avoid calling `acquireTokenSilentAsync` every time.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.microsoft_azure);
        context = MicrosoftAzureActivity.this;
        initializeUI();
        // Creates a PublicClientApplication object with res/raw/auth_config_single_account.json
        PublicClientApplication.createSingleAccountPublicClientApplication(MicrosoftAzureActivity.this,
                R.raw.auth_config_single_account,
                new IPublicClientApplication.ISingleAccountApplicationCreatedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreated(ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication application) {
                        /**
                         * This test app assumes that the app is only going to support one account.
                         * This requires "account_mode" : "SINGLE" in the config json file.
                         **/
                        loadAccount();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                        displayError(exception);
                    }
            

});
}
```

`Interactively fetching Token`:

```
    mSingleAccountApp.signIn(MicrosoftAzureActivity.this, null, getScopes(), getAuthInteractiveCallback());
```

`Load Account when already token is fetched Interactively and account is already Loaded`:

```
 private void loadAccount() {
        if (mSingleAccountApp == null) {

            Log.d("SKT","Account Not Signed In");
            return;
        }
        Log.d("SKT","Account Not Signed In#1");

        mSingleAccountApp.getCurrentAccountAsync(new ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.CurrentAccountCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAccountLoaded(@Nullable IAccount activeAccount) {
                // You can use the account data to update your UI or your app database.
                mAccount = activeAccount;
                if (activeAccount != null) {
                    Log.d("SKT","Account Already Signed In");
              
         mSingleAccountApp.acquireTokenSilentAsync(getScopes(), B2CConfiguration.getAuthorityFromPolicyName("B2C_1_SignInSignUp"), getAuthSilentCallback());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccountChanged(@Nullable IAccount priorAccount, @Nullable IAccount currentAccount) {
                if (currentAccount == null) {
                    // Perform a cleanup task as the signed-in account changed.
                    showToastOnSignOut();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull MsalException exception) {
                displayError(exception);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you must call acquireTokenAsync for this, it evaluates whether the token in cache is expired or for a different scope than being requested. If neither is true, MSAL returns the tokens from the cache, it doesn’t make any network calls and should be almost instant. You wouldn’t get any perf advantage by doing anything different as that is the minimum.

Comment: Suri - so for the best practice , I have to call `acquireTokenAsync ` each time  and the above code seems to be in the right way also?

Comment: Technically the only time you need to make a silent token call should be right before an API call. But if for some reason you need to check token validity when the app opens, then you can do that.

Comment: Suri - How can we check if the token validity is expired ? could you please  help me on that?

Comment: Call acquireTokenSilent(). Why are you looking to check this at all - it’s a check performed prior to gaining access to a protected resource anyway with MSAL.